# 'List.Contains()' causing 100% CPU usage indefinitely

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

While working on a project today I ran into this odd behavior in .NET.

I'm grabbing a list of file names and adding them to an object. However I need to filter the incoming names against a known list of "bad" names which led me to do this. (I'm by no means an advanced C# coder, still just learning it.) However, because it causes the **aspnet_wp.exe** process to run at 100% indefinitely, I assume that I'm doing something wrong with the language.

Here's my code for reference:

```
List<string> localFiles = new List<string>(); 
// I was worried the object was causing the issue so dumbed it down to this with no changed.

string path = "//<file share>/<dir>/"; 
// As I commented below yes, it's slow when it works but it's clearly not working when using the if();

List<string> omitNames = new List<string>();
omitNames.Add("Thumbs.db"); 
// This is the only item in the list when it breaks also.

FileInfo[] localFileList = new DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles();
foreach ( FileInfo item in localFileList )
{
    if(!omitNames.Contains(item.Name))
    {
        localFiles.Add(path + itemName);
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain why this code runs as an infinite loop? It looks like it really shouldn't. Also, I realize that using a `List` may not be the best approach. Is there another way to implement this cleanly?

Commenting out the `if(!){}` for `omitNames` allows the code to run properly. (Though obviously the results are not filtered.)

**UPDATE:** It was requested to put this in a console app which you'll find below. However it works perfectly. Another thing is that someone suggested that I try to simply compare it against a string. But the exact same thing happens if it's changed to this:

```
if(item.Name != "Thumbs.db")
{
    localFiles.Add(path + itemName);
}
```

Console App (which works):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace LoopKiller
{
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<string> omitNames = new List<string>();
        List<string> localFiles = new List<string>();

        omitNames.Add("Thumbs.db");

        FileInfo[] localFileList = new DirectoryInfo("c:/test/").GetFiles();

        foreach (FileInfo item in localFileList)
        {
            if (!omitNames.Contains(item.Name))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Adding " + item.Name + " to localFiles.");
                localFiles.Add(item.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("Item added to localFiles.");
            }
        }

        foreach (string item in localFiles)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: How many entries are in the directory?

Comment: Can you change this into a short but *complete* program (e.g. a console app) which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: When you debug, does it add at least one item to the list? Or does it crash immediately?

Comment: Where are `localFiles` and `itemName` defined? Could you please post more of your code?

Comment: @Oded Anywhere from 10 to a few hundred. I tried it on an entry of 1, 5 and 10 and it does the same thing. Looking at the debug it never shows localFiles.Add() being fired though as localFiles is always empty.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, I can do that, I'll post it when I complete it.

Comment: @HanletEscaño it spikes immediately, no values are ever added to localFiles.

Comment: All looks OK to me based on what's in the sample above.  Have you tried adding code to output to a debug file on each iteration of the loop so that you can confirm that this is and infitite loop and not a hang for a different reason / see if there's a particular file causing the issue / etc.  See this article on the best/recommended way to add debug/logging code: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk36c28t.aspx

Comment: You might consider use a `HashSet` for your omitNames.  It's quite fast.

Comment: Also, what happens if you run the same code on the same directory in a console app instead of in ASP.NET?

Comment: @mr.smors Seems like the .GetFiles() is what is actually causing the problem. Does it spike up if you use a directory with less files as per Oded's suggestion?

Comment: For it to be an issue with a small number of files, I would look at disk contention and issues. You may have a dud sector exactly where your test directory is.

Comment: what is the value of `path`? "`c:`" ? Ofcourse it will take time!!

Comment: @JohnLBevan I have had it out putting to a log file, it shows getting up to the check and then never goes past it.

Comment: A lot of suggestions about files, however since it works fine without the if() statement I'm inclined to disagree that the issue is the file name (it's just equating two strings and would throw a reference error) and since it works fine without the if() it's not an issue of reading files from disc. Yes it's slow reading file data from disc, but the execution goes from half a second to 5+ minutes before we have to manually kill the aspnet process on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this any quicker?

```
foreach (string item in Directory.GetFiles("c:/test/", "*.*").Select(Path.GetFileName())
    {
        if (!omitNames.Contains(item))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Adding " + item.Name + " to localFiles.");
            localFiles.Add(item.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Item added to localFiles.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure if it's faster but this does actually work against the if statement!

Answer (score 1):

Try Directory.EnumerateFiles.  If you only need the filename as a string then why get the entire FileInfo?  And I agree with putting it in a hashset.

[Directory.EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383458.aspx)

Still would not help if the problem is with the !omitNames.Contains(item.Name).  Something strange is going on there as that should be a very very fast call.

This runs in 2 milliseconds against a directory of 161 files and properly skips the two.

```
public void testFileFilter()
    {
        string path = @"c:\temp\";
        int pathLen = path.Length;
        string[] badNames = { "1692.pdf", "readme.htm" };
        List<string> goodNames = new List<string>();
        string fn;
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        foreach(String fp in System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(path))
        {
            //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(fp);
            fn = fp.Substring(pathLen);
            //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(fn);
            if(badNames.Contains(fn))
            {
                //fn = fp.Substring(pathLen);
            }
            else
            {
                goodNames.Add(fn);
            }
        }
        sw.Stop();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(goodNames.Count());
    }
```

Comment: To make a bizarre situation stranger this actually works with the if(), though it's returning the absolute file path in the name which I can't use, it has to be just the name.

Comment: Since you know the length of the path you can easily and quickly strip that off.

Comment: Use `Path.GetFileName()` to get only filename from path

Comment: Merge my answer with this one adding th select on the end and you should end up with just the filenames.

Comment: @Blam No. It works on strings. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx

Comment: @Ankush Please show me how.  I cannot make it work with string.

Comment: @Ankush Thanks for that info about Path, I ended up using that in a different part of the program today, very slick.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
List<string> localFiles = new List<string>();
// I was worried the object was causing the issue so dumbed it down to this with no changed.

string path = "//<file share>/<dir>/";
// As I commented below yes, it's slow when it works but it's clearly not working when using the if();

List<string> omitNames = new List<string>();
omitNames.Add("Thumbs.db");
// This is the only item in the list when it breaks also.

localFiles = (from files in new DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles() where !omitNames.Contains(files.Name) select path + files.Name).ToList<string>();
```

As for why you are having the issue, I do not know.  You could try putting a break point in the loop and debugging.  I find that debugging makes most problems clear.  For example, is locking on the getting of the file info.